# Custom IAuthenticationFilter in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API based on Active Directory

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, iprincipal, api-authorization

I need to implement custom authorization based on some information in on-premise Active Directory. After doing some research, I figured that best approach would be to write a custom Authentication Filter and add that information from AD to the list of claims.

So after users are authenticated by IIS using Windows Authentication, I plan to read some information and put that among the list of claims:

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var claims = new List<Claim>();
  claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userPrincipal.Name));
  claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "client"));
  claims.Add(new Claim("Accounts", "[List of accounts from AD]"));

  var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

  var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { identity });
  context.Principal = principal;
        
  Thread.CurrentPrincipal = context.Principal;
}
```

I believe that this approach will allow me to access the list of accounts from any controller. However, I am unable to add my `IAuthenticationFilter` implementation to the list of global filters using the following approach.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new ApiAuthenticationFilter())
});
```

This method required `IFilterMetaData` interface, while I have implemented `IAuthenticationFilter`. In previous Web API versions, we were able to access `HttpConfiguration` in `Application_Start()` method, but in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I am unable to find a way to add my filter to `HttpConfiguration`.

Could you please tell me if that's the right approach, or I should try implementing the `IActionFilter` interface? Or a different approach altogether.

Thanks!

Comment: You can set that globally using `custom action filter middleware` .[`you can check more details on the official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#implementation)

Comment: @md-farid-uddin-kiron Thanks for pointing that out, I believe I found a better solution and posted here.

Answer (score 2):

I figured `IAuthenticationFilter` is not the right approach anymore to add Claims to  the `ClaimsPrincipal`. There's another interface `IClaimsTransformation` that does exactly what I wanted.

The example posted on ASP.NET website was creating a new `ClaimsIdentity` instance to the `ClaimsPrincipal` while I was able to achieve that by just adding to existing list of claims:

```
public class MyClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IActiveDirectoryService _activeDirectoryService;

    public MyClaimsTransformation(IActiveDirectoryService activeDirectoryService)
    {
        _activeDirectoryService = activeDirectoryService;
    }


    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var identity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsAuthenticated);

        if (identity == null)
        {
            return principal;
        }

        var user = _activeDirectoryService.GetUser(principal.Identity as WindowsIdentity);

        // Add or replace identity.Claims

        if (!principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == MyClaimTypes.ACCOUNTS))
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(MyClaimTypes.ACCOUNTS, user.Accounts));

        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

Another advantage of using `IClaimsTransformation` is to be able to inject dependencies through .Net core DI container.

In my Program.cs, I was unable to make it work using the recommended Authentication method:

`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

However, using Negotiate worked for me:

`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();`

Finally, add our custom `IClaimsTranformation` implementation to services:

```
// Claim transformation
builder.Services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformation>();
```

In the past, it had to be done inside `ConfigureServices()` method

More details about IClaimsTransformation are available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I've implemented a complete implementation of IClaimsTransformation for both MinimalApis and ControllerBased APIs for you
https://github.com/amiru3f/remote-claim-transformation

Please note that ClaimsTransofmer is not responsible for authorization/authentication. It's just responsible to fill up your claims and you can ensure if the User has required claims or not